# Can there be two different left most derevations for a grammar?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

Suppose there is a CFG with the rules

```
S--> Aa
A--> Bb
B--> A
B--> Epsilon
```

To my best understanding the left most derivation would go like this..

```
 S==> Aa ==>  Bba ==> Aba ==> Bbba ==> bba
```

or

```
 S==> Aa ==>  Bba ==> Aba ==> Bbba ==> Abba ==> Bbbba ==> bbba
```

or

```
 S==> Aa ==> Bba ==> ba
```

Of these which is the true left most derivation of the language? If it is true that all of them are valid left most derivations,why is it that many text book talk about left most derivations of a language rather than a final string??

Comment: Welcome! Please remember to upvote answers you like, and accept the one that helped you mist. "Thank you" comments are well-intended but considered superfluous on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A leftmost derivation of a string in the language defined by a
grammar $G$ characterizes a parse-tree for that string. It is a way of
describing the parse tree, which is unique for each parse tree.

But to answer the specifics of your question, there is no lefmost
derivation of a language, only of the strings of a
language. Furthermore, since a leftmost derivation is a sequence of
grammar rules applications to produce the string, a leftmost
derivation is necessarily defined with respect to a specific
grammar. Indeed, the language does not really matter, only the grammar
and a string derived with that grammar.

If a string has only a single derivation for a grammar $G$, it is said
*unambiguous* for that grammar. When it has several, it is said
*ambiguous* for that grammar. When it has none, it does not belong to
the language generated by the grammar.

A grammar is ambiguous if it generate at least one ambiguous
string. It is unambiguous if every string in its language is
unambiguous.

The grammar in your question is unambiguous. Each of the derivations
you give is a leftmost derivation, but each for a different string in
the language of the grammar.

Actually, this grammar is so simple that it has only leftmost
derivations, because there is at most one non-terminal in each rule
right-hand side. But a grammar can have only leftmost derivations and be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

A *derivation* is a "proof" that a certain word is generated by a certain grammar. The grammar itself doesn't have a left-most derivation. Each word in the grammar has left-most derivations, possibly more than one if the grammar is ambiguous.